# Showing uniqueness of elements in subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Show that if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces of a vector space with
 $W_1\cap W_2 = \{0\}$, then for each vector $x\in W_1 + W_2$ there are unique vectors $x_1\in W_1$ and $x_2\in W_2$ such that $x = x_1 + x_2$.

My issue has always been trying to show uniqueness. Hints/suggestions?

Comment: Pretty much every time you want to prove something is unique, you suppose for the sake of contradiction that it is not unique.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x_1+x_2=y_1+y_2$, with $x_1,y_1\in W_1$ and $x_2,y_2\in W_2$. Then consider
$$
v=x_1-y_1=y_2-x_2
$$
What can you say about $v=x_1-y_1$? And what about $v=y_2-x_2$? Then $v\in\dots$ and so…

Comment: I figured out most of it, but one aspect still bothers me. I know the condition is that W1 (intersect) W2 is 0, but why am i able to say 0 = v = x1 - y1? The next step would be to say x1 = y1 to show uniqueness, but why the setting equal to 0?

Comment: @dc3rd The equality $x_1-y_1=y_2-x_2$ comes from the hypothesis $x_1+x_2=y_1+y_2$. Set $v=x_1-y_1$, just for giving it a name. Then $v\in W_1$. On the other hand, $v=y_2-x_2\in W_2$. Thus $v\in W_1\cap W_2$.